# Single Allele to Biallelic Conditional on Major and Minor Allele Columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame with several individuals as columns and SNPs as rows. Each column has a single allele (e.g. G or A or N (if not called). There are also columns with the major and (seperate column) minor alleles for each SNP. I am trying to convert the single allele value into a bialleic value for each value based on the major and minor allele columns (so if the allele for an individual is the major allele, I want to paste the minor allele after it with a space separator and vice versa). If the value is missing (N) I'd like to replace it with 0 0. The idea here is to format these data for Plink.

So far I have tried to use the ifelse function but without success. Any suggestions as to how to get the biallelic values here? Thank you very much! I've included a made up data set in the formats I am referring to.

What I have now:

```
rs#       major minor   ind1    ind2    ind3    ind4
rs123456    A    G      A       A       A        G
rs123457    G    C      C       G       C        G
rs123458    C    G      C       C       G        C
rs123459    T    A      A       T       N        T
```

What I would like to

```
rs        major minor   ind1    ind2    ind3    ind4
rs123456    A    G      A G     A G     A G      G A
rs123457    G    C      C G     G C     C G      G C
rs123458    C    A      C A     C A     A C      C A
rs123459    T    A      A T     T A     0 0      T A
```

Thanks!
Rob

Comment: Why do you have to rely on minor/major? Nucleotides always have its complement purine/pyrimidine (not excluding RNA). It should be a breeze to generate that and paste it together into a string.

Comment: Thanks! I did not do a great job with my example, but in this case since these are single nucleotide polymorphisms, they do not necessarily follow the complementary nucleotide rules such as with replication. I can edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: Please show the most complex example you expect.

Comment: Hi Roman, actually, I think I can get away with the single alleles as they were. Sorry to waste your time!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing things. Go through your data row-wise and find complement from minor/major. Notice that your input and expected output do not match.

```
xy <- read.table(text = "rs       major minor   ind1    ind2    ind3    ind4
rs123456    A    G      A       A       A        G
rs123457    G    C      C       G       C        G
rs123458    C    G      C       C       G        C
rs123459    T    A      A       T       N        T", header = TRUE)
xy

out <- apply(xy, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) {
  findind <- grepl("^ind", names(x))
  x[x %in% x["major"] & findind] <- paste(x[x %in% x["major"] & findind], x["minor"])
  x[x %in% x["minor"] & findind] <- paste(x[x %in% x["minor"] & findind], x["major"])
  x[x %in% "N"] <- "0 0"
  list(x)
})
out <- sapply(out, "[", 1)
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, out))

        rs major minor ind1 ind2 ind3 ind4
1 rs123456     A     G  A G  A G  A G  G A
2 rs123457     G     C  C G  G C  C G  G C
3 rs123458     C     G  C G  C G  G C  C G
4 rs123459     T     A  A T  T A  0 0  T A
```